# Is threading the right way to setup an inotify and an API server in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, rest, inotify

I'm coding an application with the following structure.

1) **inotify part**: Monitor a directory and kickoff a workflow when new files are added

2) **api part**: Setup an API server to be able to add/remove actions to be performed during the workflow.

I need both of these to be running at the same time. What is the best way to set this up? Should I use multithreading or write two separate services?

Please let me know if this is a duplicate and has already been answered somewhere else.

Thanks!

Comment: Do the state changes that the API part makes persist across program restarts and system reboots? I.e. do you have to have a database anyway? If so, then separating them into two distinct programs might be easiest.

Comment: @Robᵩ Yes. The API has two calls. One to add actions into a database, and another to remove actions from a database. Thanks for the advice.